Why an unnecessary project is built when building a project?
I am building a project for several versions of the framework. And I need to output a message after building the release of each version, for this I use AfterTargets. But AfterTarget is triggered 3 times instead of the required two. What could be the reason?
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>False</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
        <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>False</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!--Multiple Revit build adjustments.-->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <TargetFrameworks>net47; net48</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47'">

    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48'">

    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name ="BuiltTest" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="BUILD: $(Configuration) $(TargetFramework)"/>
    </Target>

</Project>

Output:
Rebuild started at 18:27...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MSBuild, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Restored C:\Users\myank\Documents\_code\_my projects\MSBuild\MSBuild\MSBuild.csproj (in 2 ms).
1>MSBuild -> C:\Users\myank\Documents\_code\_my projects\MSBuild\MSBuild\bin\Release\net48\MSBuild.dll
1>BUILD: Release net48
1>MSBuild -> C:\Users\myank\Documents\_code\_my projects\MSBuild\MSBuild\bin\Release\net47\MSBuild.dll
1>BUILD: Release net47
1>BUILD: Release
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild completed at 18:27 and took 00.775 seconds ==========

Full Output:
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        * ms  Clean                                      1 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputeTargetFrameworkItems               1 calls
1>        0 ms  AddSourceRevisionToInformationalVersion    2 calls
1>        0 ms  InitializeSourceControlInformation         2 calls
1>        0 ms  _InitializeSourceControlInformationFromSourceControlManager   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _SourceLinkHasSingleProvider               2 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    2 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute        2 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFile            2 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileShouldRun   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                     2 calls
1>        0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                 2 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareResources                           2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResGen                                     2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckContainersPackage                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreResGen                                 2 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeResGen                               2 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareResourceNames                       2 calls
1>        0 ms  CreateCustomManifestResourceNames          2 calls
1>        0 ms  CopyAdditionalFiles                        2 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterMarkupCompilePass1                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  ExpressionBuildExtension                   2 calls
1>        0 ms  ValidationExtension                        2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveReferences                          2 calls
1>        0 ms  ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades          2 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateAssemblyInfo                       2 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeCompile                              2 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateCompiledExpressionsTempFile        2 calls
1>        0 ms  DesignTimeMarkupCompilation                2 calls
1>        0 ms  Build                                      3 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 2 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  2 calls
1>        0 ms  PrepareForRun                              2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory          2 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromThisProject   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromTransitiveProjectReferences   2 calls
1>        0 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs        2 calls
1>        0 ms  _PopulateCommonStateForGetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems   2 calls
1>        0 ms  GetTargetPath                              2 calls
1>        0 ms  GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker     2 calls
1>        0 ms  CreateSatelliteAssemblies                  2 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs           2 calls
1>        0 ms  Compile                                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  _AfterCompileWinFXInternal                 2 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterCompileWinFX                          2 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterCompile                               2 calls
1>        0 ms  GenerateSourceLinkFile                     2 calls
1>        0 ms  _InitializeSourceRootMappedPathsOpt        2 calls
1>        0 ms  _InitializeSourceRootMappedPathsFromSourceControl   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetSourceLinkFilePath                     2 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputeSkipAnalyzers                      2 calls
1>        0 ms  _BeforeVBCSCoreCompile                     2 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                     2 calls
1>        0 ms  _RemoveZipFileSuggestedRedirect            1 calls
1>        0 ms  Rebuild                                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  IncludeTransitiveProjectReferences         2 calls
1>        0 ms  _AddOutputPathToGlobalPropertiesToRemove   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild         2 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetProjectJsonPath                        2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedCppNETCoreVersion      2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveLockFileCopyLocalFiles              2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveLockFileAnalyzers                   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedTargetFrameworkAndFeatureCombination   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _ComputePackageReferencePublish            2 calls
1>        0 ms  _DefaultMicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary        2 calls
1>        0 ms  _SdkBeforeClean                            2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedArtifactsPath          2 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeClean                                2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForLanguageAndFeatureCombinationSupport   2 calls
1>        0 ms  EnableIntermediateOutputPathMismatchWarning   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForObsoleteDotNetCliToolReferences   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _AddMicrosoftNetCompilerToolsetFrameworkPackage   2 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanReferencedProjects                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanPublishFolder                         2 calls
1>        0 ms  IncludeTargetingPackReference              2 calls
1>        0 ms  RemoveManagedWinRTComponentWinMDReferences   2 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CollectTargetFrameworkForTelemetry        2 calls
1>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                          2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                       2 calls
1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          2 calls
1>        0 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                        2 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanXsdCodeGen                            2 calls
1>        0 ms  _SetBuildInnerTarget                       1 calls
1>        1 ms  PrepareProjectReferences                   2 calls
1>        1 ms  AddImplicitDefineConstants                 2 calls
1>        1 ms  _HandlePackageFileConflicts                2 calls
1>        1 ms  AfterClean                                 2 calls
1>        1 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                    2 calls
1>        1 ms  ValidateExecutableReferences               2 calls
1>        1 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   2 calls
1>        1 ms  DesignTimeXamlMarkupCompilation            2 calls
1>        1 ms  AfterResGen                                2 calls
1>        1 ms  SourceControlManagerPublishTranslatedUrls   2 calls
1>        1 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  2 calls
1>        1 ms  _GetRestoreProjectStyle                    2 calls
1>        1 ms  TranslateGitLabUrlsInSourceControlInformation   2 calls
1>        1 ms  FileClassification                         2 calls
1>        1 ms  _ComputeToolPackInputsToProcessFrameworkReferences   2 calls
1>        1 ms  ResolveLockFileReferences                  2 calls
1>        1 ms  CollectPackageReferences                   2 calls
1>        1 ms  FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences       2 calls
1>        1 ms  GetAssemblyAttributes                      2 calls
1>        1 ms  ValidateCommandLineProperties              2 calls
1>        1 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    2 calls
1>        1 ms  _TouchLastBuildWithSkipAnalyzers           2 calls
1>        1 ms  InitializeSourceRootMappedPaths            2 calls
1>        1 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 2 calls
1>        1 ms  BeforeBuild                                2 calls
1>        1 ms  TranslateBitbucketGitUrlsInSourceControlInformation   2 calls
1>        1 ms  IgnoreJavaScriptOutputAssembly             2 calls
1>        1 ms  PreXsdCodeGen                              2 calls
1>        2 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                     2 calls
1>        2 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfigFileCore        2 calls
1>        2 ms  PrepareForBuild                            2 calls
1>        2 ms  TranslateAzureReposGitUrlsInSourceControlInformation   2 calls
1>        2 ms  BuiltTest                                  3 calls
1>        2 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   2 calls
1>        2 ms  AssignTargetPaths                          2 calls
1>        2 ms  TranslateGitHubUrlsInSourceControlInformation   2 calls
1>        2 ms  ImplicitlyExpandNETStandardFacades         2 calls
1>        2 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                         2 calls
1>        2 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties        2 calls
1>        3 ms  IncrementalClean                           2 calls
1>        3 ms  _InitializeAzureReposGitSourceLinkUrl      4 calls
1>        3 ms  GenerateNETCompatibleDefineConstants       2 calls
1>        3 ms  _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties   2 calls
1>        3 ms  InitializeSourceControlInformationFromSourceControlManager   2 calls
1>        3 ms  _InitializeGitHubSourceLinkUrl             4 calls
1>        3 ms  _InitializeGitLabSourceLinkUrl             4 calls
1>        3 ms  _GenerateCompileDependencyCache            2 calls
1>        3 ms  _InitializeBitbucketGitSourceLinkUrl       4 calls
1>        3 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              2 calls
1>        4 ms  CreateGeneratedAssemblyInfoInputsCacheFile   2 calls
1>        4 ms  _GenerateSourceLinkFile                    2 calls
1>        4 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites         2 calls
1>        6 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                 2 calls
1>        8 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  2 calls
1>        9 ms  CoreClean                                  2 calls
1>       13 ms  CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo                   2 calls
1>       60 ms  CoreCompile                                2 calls
1>      142 ms  DispatchToInnerBuilds                      1 calls
1>      171 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                       2 calls
1>        (* = timing was not recorded because of reentrancy)
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        * ms  MSBuild                                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.MapSourceRoots   2 calls
1>        0 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.SourceLinkHasSingleProvider   2 calls
1>        0 ms  GetDependsOnNETStandard                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           2 calls
1>        0 ms  ResolvePackageFileConflicts                2 calls
1>        0 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          2 calls
1>        0 ms  SetRidAgnosticValueForProjects             2 calls
1>        0 ms  JoinItems                                  2 calls
1>        0 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           6 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignCulture                              2 calls
1>        0 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   2 calls
1>        0 ms  AllowEmptyTelemetry                        2 calls
1>        0 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  4 calls
1>        1 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          4 calls
1>        1 ms  Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository   2 calls
1>        1 ms  ValidateExecutableReferences               2 calls
1>        1 ms  MakeDir                                    4 calls
1>        1 ms  Hash                                       4 calls
1>        1 ms  GetRestoreProjectStyleTask                 2 calls
1>        1 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitLab.TranslateRepositoryUrls   2 calls
1>        1 ms  GenerateMSBuildEditorConfig                2 calls
1>        1 ms  CheckForDuplicateNuGetItemsTask            2 calls
1>        1 ms  Touch                                      2 calls
1>        1 ms  GetAssemblyVersion                         2 calls
1>        1 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 2 calls
1>        1 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      2 calls
1>        1 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git.TranslateRepositoryUrls   2 calls
1>        1 ms  CallTarget                                 6 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitLab.GetSourceLinkUrl   4 calls
1>        2 ms  WriteLinesToFile                           8 calls
1>        2 ms  CheckForDuplicateItems                     6 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git.TranslateRepositoryUrls   2 calls
1>        2 ms  Message                                    9 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.GetSourceLinkUrl   4 calls
1>        2 ms  AssignTargetPath                          14 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.TranslateRepositoryUrls   2 calls
1>        2 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Bitbucket.Git.GetSourceLinkUrl   4 calls
1>        3 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git.GetSourceLinkUrl   4 calls
1>        3 ms  FindUnderPath                             14 calls
1>        3 ms  Microsoft.SourceLink.Common.GenerateSourceLinkFile   2 calls
1>        4 ms  Copy                                       4 calls
1>        6 ms  Delete                                     8 calls
1>        8 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   2 calls
1>       13 ms  WriteCodeFragment                          2 calls
1>       59 ms  Csc                                        2 calls
1>      171 ms  ResolvePackageAssets                       2 calls
1>        (* = timing was not recorded because of reentrancy)
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.39
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild completed at 18:05 and took 00.954 seconds ==========

I've tried using other tags, but it's still like 3 projects are being built instead of two.

Change the verbosity from minimal to normal so you can see more of what is going on. There should not be a space in TargetFrameworks, i.e. use <TargetFrameworks>net47;net48</TargetFrameworks>.

I removed unnecessary stuff because output gives too much information: here you can see the problem why Build is called 3 times: 1>        0 ms  Build                                      3 calls

@ДжонатанДоддс Thanks for the tip I found a solution for myself I will use the BeforeBuild tag, it is called twice. But I'm still wondering why the project is built 3 times, do you have any ideas?

The project should not be built 3 times but the output you provide doesn't include enough information to understand what is happening.

@JonathanDodds Apologies, I added Summary above to the question. It shows that Build is called 3 times. I can't add the full output as there is a character limit

That level of details can only be found in MSBuild bin log, https://msbuildlog.com/ so you should collect and analyze to learn what exactly happened.

@LexLi Thanks, I'll try msbuildlog.com and if it gives me an answer I'll post it here.
